# Typescript Type Based on Input Parameter Type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am trying to do something as follows

```js
const useTeams = (urlFriendlyNameOrId?: string) => {
    const [team, setTeam] = useState<>();
    // Inside of useState<> I want it to evaluate to <Team> if there is a provided string or <Team[]> otherwise
    // I have tried useState<typeof urlFriendlyNameOrId extends string ? Team : Team[]>() will just always give me Team[]
    // I have tried useState<typeof urlFriendlyNameOrId === 'string' ? Team : Team[]() get error about always being false
    ...
    return { team, setTeam };
}
```

where it will generate correct typing based on the type of a parameter. I have even gone as far as to rewrite the function using generics but I still can't get that to work.

```js
function useTeams<T extends string | undefined>(urlFriendlyNameOrId?: T) {
    const [team, setTeam] = useState<>();
    // useState<T extends string ? Team : Team[]>()
    // useState<typeof T extends string ? Team : Team[]>()
}
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong here, what is the wider context you want to achieve? My concern is - you should init hook without condition, as this is the rule, that means that hook should always deal with union `Team | Team[]`, you cannot narrow it at level of initialization, you can do that after.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was going a little *too* generic with what I wanted.I wanted a general case where if you didn't provide a URL it would return all the teams while if you provided a URL it would just return that team. I might want to split this up into two different hooks or refactor it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not directly answer the question as I think you went to some wrong path here. It is not possible to use conditionally hooks, it means that if your hook can work with both - array and single object, that is also the type definition.

As in order to narrow the type the only way would be set type guards, such cannot be done with hooks, so type guards needs to be set after initialization.

Take a look at below code, I think this is what you really want to do:

```
// just example type as you haven't provided such
type Team = {
    name: string;
}

function useTeams(urlFriendlyNameOrId?: string) {
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState<Team | Team[]>(
urlFriendlyNameOrId ? {name: urlFriendlyNameOrId} : []);

    if (Array.isArray(teams)) {
        teams // array
    } else {
        teams // single team
    }
}
```

Pay attention that hook works with union `Team | Team[]`, I am conditionally passing the initial value `urlFriendlyNameOrId ? {name: urlFriendlyNameOrId} : []`, and also I am doing type narrowing in conditions after.

---

One last take from me, as I am for such cases always advocate for less ad-hoc polymorphism I would suggest to simplify the type into `Team[]`. Take a look how your code would change for better:

```
function useTeams(urlFriendlyNameOrId?: string) {
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState<Team[]>(
urlFriendlyNameOrId ? [{name: urlFriendlyNameOrId}] : []);

    teams // it can be or empty or one element array of teams
}
```

Take a look at my article about this subject - [Function flexibility considered harmful](https://dev.to/macsikora/function-flexibility-considered-harmful-447n)